# Using time.sleep() in asyncio program

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio, openai-api

I'm working on an asyncio-based program where I need to introduce a delay using time.sleep() (I use openai.ChatCompletion.create which using tome.sleep() inside loop).
I understand that time.sleep() is a blocking operation and goes against the asynchronous nature of asyncio.
Any guidance or alternative approaches would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

I'm trying to use asyncio.get_running_loop() and asyncio.gather, but it doesn't work
Example:

```
`import asyncio
import time


async def test_loop():
    loop_counter = 0
    while True:
        print('loop')
        time.sleep(2)
        if loop_counter >= 5:
            break
        loop_counter += 1


async def delay_msgs():
    print('run msgs')
    await asyncio.sleep(5)
    print('asdf')
    await asyncio.sleep(10)
    print("qwerty")


async def main():
    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
    task1 = asyncio.create_task(delay_msgs())
    task2 = loop.create_task(test_loop())
    await asyncio.gather(task1, task2)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())`
```

Comment: You should use `asyncio.sleep(time_in_seconds)`

Comment: asyncio.sleep(time_in_seconds) - this only helps in this example, but I'm using a library that uses time.sleep

Comment: There is [`asyncio.to_thread`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#running-in-threads) or `loop.run_in_executor` for this.

Comment: you're right, thanks. example: await asyncio.gather(asyncio.to_thread(test_loop), delay_msgs())